# Wordpress/PHP - load stylesheet when URL parameter is present

Tags: php, wordpress, url, parameters, stylesheet

Hoping to find a way to make a Wordpress site load a stylesheet only when a URL parameter is present. For example when http://www.somesite.com is loaded, it will use whatever stylesheets are in use by the theme. But if a specific URL parameter is used, an additional stylesheet will be called. Example http://www.somesite.com?useAltCss=yes. In this case, an additional stylesheet is loaded AFTER the theme stylsheets. This gives me an opportunity to override theme styles only when the URL parameter is used, and test style/laylout changes without effecting public viewing.

I assume a coding modification would be needed for header.php. The following is not working PHP syntax but gives you an idea of I'm looking for:

```
<?php
    $param = ($_GET["useAltCss"]);
    if($param == 'yes') {
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
?>
```

Update:

Looks like my original code was close I just had to change line 4 from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />
```

to:

```
echo('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />');
```

While this is working, im wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this. If I navigate to a new page to test style changes, I have to manually add the URL parameter. It would be great if it somehow locked in the custom.css stylsheet... maybe using a cookie or session? I wonder how it could be toggled on/off. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only using this for yourself then I think your method is fine... However - for anyone else stumbling upon this question - I want to emphasize that this is *not* doing things by the book. The second method suggested below is an ok solution, but the first should only be used for a very temporary situation (opening a session on each page load is likely unnecessary and will cause some performance degradation).

Stylesheets also shouldn't be printed manually (ie. using `<link[...]>`), instead use `wp_enqueue_style()` in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

### Method 1

To keep the "setting" instead of having to manually type it on every page load you can use a session like this:

You need to open a session before headers are sent, so put this in `wp-config.php`:

```
//Start the session if it isn't already
session_start();
```

The rest goes wherever you want your stylesheet (most likely in `header.php`):

```
//Check if the parameter is set
if (isset($_GET["useAltCss"])) {
    if($_GET["useAltCss"] === 'yes') {
        //Adjust the session
        $_SESSION['useAltCss'] = true;
    } else {
        /**
         * If set to anything other than "yes", assume it's being switched
         * off, and adjust the session
         */
        $_SESSION['useAltCss'] = false;
    }
}
//Check if the session variable exists, and is currently true
if (isset($_SESSION['useAltCss']) && $_SESSION['useAltCss'] === true) {
    //And print your stylesheet
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />';
}
```

### Method 2

Another (simpler) option would be to simply check if the current user is logged in and has the capability to edit the theme (which I expect you do):

```
if (current_user_can('edit_themes')) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />';
}
```

- Documentation: [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

...this of course won't allow you to switch back and forth - except by logging in and out each time.

Comment: Thanks, your second option is interesting and one I hadn't considered. I'll try them both. thanks much.

Comment: Ok, so I tried your session based approach. If the URL param is present with a value of 'yes', the custom stylesheet loaded but as soon as I navigate to another page or reload current page without the URL param the custom stylesheet is NOT loaded. The session does not seem to be sticking from page to page.

Comment: Sounds like a general problem with sessions on your server unless I made some typo (that I still can't spot) - what do you get if you `die(var_export($_SESSION, true))` immidiately after the `session_start()` call?

Comment: Your die command was added following session_start(). This appears in the HTML source: 'array ()' and the page end there. No body/footer HTML is parsed.

Comment: Not sure if this matters but this Wordpress site is running on IIS7 (Windows Server 2008 R2), not your typical Unix flavor server.

Comment: Another update: I made some php.ini updates and rebooited IIS. Also set various permissions on the php/session folder. Now when I run your die function I get this: array ( 'counter' => 5, 'useAltCss' => true, ). The session now seems to be sticking as intended. Solved.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon. While it sticks in Chrome, any other browser or workstation (any browser, even Chrome) it doesn't stick page to page. *confused*

Comment: Hehe, I don't know why I always assume everyone uses a lamp stack for wordpress just because I do :p But a working session setup is obviously a prerequisite for sessions no matter the OS and server, so you'll probably be happier with that out of the way anyway :)

Comment: Do you happen to also be on `http://localhost` ? Some browsers are **seriously** restrictive in what they allow there (ie. cookies are needed for sessions, and they may be disallowed on localhost by some browsers).

Comment: No, I have it running on a live WP site.

Comment: This is the content of the session file created when the URL param is used: useAltCss|b:1; When I visit a different page, a new/unique session file is created and is blank

Comment: Ok, my next guess is that you are logged in in Chrome, but not in the others, and therefore you have no session open by the time this is executed (and the `session_start()` call actually wont work because the headers are already sent). Try to move just the `session_start();` line to your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Alright ... The problem seemed to be centered around the fact that each page visited was creating a unique session file. If I first visited the home page, then 10 sub pages, 11 sessions files were created ... all blank without the ussAltCss variable. When I moved the session_start() function to line 2 of wp-config.php only one session file is created regardless of how many pages are visited. Fingers crossed this one holds. So far all browsers are sticking.

Comment: Ok sounds good. I'm off to bed, so final comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the latest change, and to emphasize that this is not a good permanent solution. You should also be aware of that.

Comment: You were most helpful. Kooodos.